# Nightwatch - How to determine if scroll top button has worked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

Anyone know how to check if a scroll top button has worked well and the current position of the scroll is 0 to top?

I have tried a lot of nightwatch functions and none of them has worked well.

I only want to know if the distance to top is 0, but any nightwatch function do that.

My current code is this:

```
'Homepage - ScrollTop' : function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://prueba.com')
      .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000, 'Page completely loaded')
      .moveToElement('footer', 10, 10).pause(1000)
      .assert.visible('.scroll_top', 'ScrollTop button is visible')
      .assert.cssClassPresent('.scroll_top', "in")
      .click('#cookie-bar .cerrar').pause(1000)
      .click('.scroll_top').pause(1000)
      .getLocationInView('#cars_header', function(result) {
        console.log(result.value)
      })
      .end()
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is no built-in option in Nightwatch. What works for me is extracting the scrollTop value via a [command](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#commands) and asserting it afterwards. Here is something you may try putting before calling `end()`.

```
.execute(`return document.querySelector(YOUR_ELEMENT_SELECTOR').scrollTop;`, function(result) {
    this.assert.ok(result.value === 0, `actual scrollTop: ${result.value}, expected 0`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked, as element I put html to check the scroll of the page :)